# Relatively placed overlay based on string length

Tags: spacing, chapters, strings

## Background

Using ConTeXt I'm trying to reproduce the following result:

[image: Overlay]

The problem centres around the first character of the chapter title being offset a relative distance from the chapter title.

## Problem

I've tried styling the chapter as follows:

```
\definespotcolor[ColourSecondary][h=9A957A]
\definespotcolor[ColourSecondaryLightest]
  [ColourSecondary][a=1,t=.2]

\definefont[StyleFontChapterCharacter]
  [SerifItalic scaled 20000]

\defineframed[StyleChapterFramed][
  frame=on,
  align={flushright,low,nothyphenated,verytolerant},
  width=\dimexpr\textwidth-(.2\marginwidth),
  height=\textheight,%+0.6\footerheight,
]

\define[1]\StyleChapter{%
  \StyleChapterFramed{%
\startoverlay
    \color[ColourSecondaryLightest]{%
      \StyleFontChapterCharacter\getfirstcharacter{#1}\firstcharacter}
      #1
\stopoverlay
  }
}
```

Using `\hskip` forces the first letter (by moving the chapter title?):

```
  \hskip-1em#1
```

This produces:

[image: Lunch Skip]

Changing the frame so that it extends beyond the footer is easy enough, but the `low` parameter causes the entire chapter title to move down.

I have tried `\vspace` and `\vskip`, but neither seem to overpower the `low` parameter.

I also tried maneuvering the text by calculating the offset based on the dimensions for the title text, but could not find a viable solution (i.e., how do you determine how much space a word takes up on a page?).

## Question

How would you relocate just the first letter of the title so that it is offset below the title itself, as shown in the desired result, regardless of the length of the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that [`align={left`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Right_and_left) means *right-aligned* (i.e., ragged *left*):

```
\defineframed[StyleChapterFramed][
  frame=off,
  align={left,low,nothyphenated,verytolerant},
  width=\dimexpr\textwidth-(.2\marginwidth),
  height=\dimexpr\textheight+0.5\footerheight,
]
```

Then use a nested frame to keep the [overlain](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Overlays) large letter and its word together:

```
\define[1]\StyleChapter{%
  \StyleChapterFramed{%
    \framed[align=right, frame=off]{%
      \startoverlay
        \color[ColourSecondaryLightest]{%
          \StyleFontChapterCharacter\getfirstcharacter{#1}%
          \firstcharacter}
        \vskip-1.9em\hskip1.2em#1
      \stopoverlay
    }
  }
}
```

This produces the following, fairly appetizing, result:

[image: Ragged Left is Right-Aligned]